# Checking bitmask in Swift

Tags: swift

Tried the code below, doesn't compile

```c
if button.keyEquivalentModifierMask & NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask != 0 {
}
```

What's a proper way to check for bitmasks in Swift?

Comment: what is the error message do you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyEquivalentModifierMask` is a `Int`, whereas `NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask` is an enum-like with `UInt` raw value, so you have to read the `rawValue` out of it and convert `keyEquivalentModifierMask` to `Uint`:

```
if UInt(button.keyEquivalentModifierMask) & NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask.rawValue > 0 {
}
```

Comment: OMG the code is longer that its objc equivalent. Didn't notice that `keyEquivalentModifierMask` is a `Int` while `NSEventModifierFlags` has `UInt` raw value. What an API design!

Comment: That gets unnoticed as long as the language provides implicit cast... in swift instead everything must be explicitly converted

Comment: You should file a bug report. It ought to be possible to improve the conversion of those types and methods to Swift.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough points to post a comment but @Greg Parker, in Swift 2 there is a neater way. NSEventModifierFlags are an OptionSetType enum. Flags can be checked with the contains() method. So something like...

```
NSEvent.modifierFlags().contains(.ShiftKeyMask)
```

...works. Not the shortest code but neater.

(if anyone can give me some points I could comment directly next time!)